# GeoServer WFS: namespace not returned for fields on DescribeFeatureType

Tags: wfs

I am connecting to a WFS server and have done a DescribeFeatureType request. The layer I am querying is in a namespace.

Doing a GET request with the following body to an endpoint ending in /geoserver/wfs

```
<wfs:DescribeFeatureType service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"><wfs:TypeName>namespace:polygons</wfs:TypeName></wfs:DescribeFeatureType>
```

When I get the result, the field names are returned without namespaces. Am I doing something wrong?

The result I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://namespace.gov.uk/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:namespace="https://namespace.gov.uk/" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="https://my-url/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd" />
<xsd:complexType name="polygonsType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="site_ref" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
```

etc...

Comment: how **exactly** are you requesting the `DescribeFeatureType`?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: to which endpoint? is there a workspace involved in the URL? - please show **exactly** what you send and what you receive back

Comment: I've updated the question again

Answer (score 0):

If I send your request

```
<wfs:DescribeFeatureType service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/w  /2.0"><wfs:TypeName>topp:states</wfs:TypeName></wfs:DescribeFeatureType>
```

to my local geoserver

```
curl -v --data-ascii @/tmp/desc.xml "http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.20.4/wfs" -H 'content-type: text/xml'
```

this is what I get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" 
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver-2.20.4/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="statesType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_FIPS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SUB_REGION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_ABBR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LAND_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WATER_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PERSONS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FAMILIES" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HOUSHOLD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WORKERS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DRVALONE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CARPOOL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PUBTRANS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EMPLOYED" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UNEMPLOY" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SERVICE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MANUAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SAMP_POP" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="states" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="topp:statesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

as you can see the target namespace `targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp"` is clearly present.